# Command Line XSLT

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, command-line, ssis

I have an XSL file that gets applied to the source XML file (huge file - more than 1GB in size).

I am running this is SSIS 2012 using the XML component.  I get an out-of-memory exception within SSIS running in 64 bit mode - it uses up 10GB of RAM before it conks out.  I have 20GB RAM total, and it is really funny to me that I get an out of memory, but when I have 50% unused RAM.

I want to test out applying the XSL on command line to check if this is an SSIS issue or underlying .Net issue.

How do I apply XSL to an XML file on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my memory problem using a SCRIPT TASK instead of the XML component for this.  Here is *sample* code:

```
Dim xslt As New XslTransform()
xslt.Load("C:\Temp\Template.xslt")
xslt.Transform("C:\Temp\XMLSource.xml", "C:\Temp\XMLSource_Revised.xml")
```